# Resolving a parameter pattern without a specific character at front and back

Tags: php, regex

For practice i'm creating my own PHP router. This router could take in parameters which are specified like this:

> {i:variableName}

The `i` stands for the parameter type (in this case integer) and the `variableName` stands for the variablename.

A single routing URI could look like this:

> /home/{i:id}-{s:noVar}/{m:varName}/{s:someOther}

I've created the following regex pattern for this purpose:

```
[^{}]*({((?<type>\D):)?(?<name>[a-zA-Z_-ÿ][a-zA-Z0-9_-ÿ]+)})[^{}]*
```

For not having 2 parameters next to each other, and having a character next to it, I expanded the regex with this piece:

```
[^{}]*
```

An example for this is that I won't be able to do stuff like:

> /home/{i:id}{s:noVar}/{m:varName}{s:someOther}

There need to be characters between them.

I thought this piece of regex would do, "Do not include zero or more of the `{`  or `}` character.

When I run this regex on a pattern like `/home/{i:id}{s:noVar}/{m:varName}/{s:someOther}`, it still retrieves all the parameters, even the ones that are next to each other.

How is this possible and how can I make it so that the regex will only retrieve parameters that aren't next to each other?

Comment: Enclose your first pattern with `(?<!})` and `(?!{)`. See https://regex101.com/r/fF5wQ3/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What do you mean? I'm still a beginner on regular expressions.

Comment: Are you aware that `_-ÿ`  creates a range? Is that your intent?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's for a variable name, I basicly googled it. I guess it's off topic now, but what does it exactly do?

Comment: I do not understand one point: is the `i:` really optional? Check if [`(?:{(?:[a-zA-Z]:)?[a-zA-Z_]\w*}){2,}(*SKIP)(*F)|({(?:(?<type>[a-zA-Z]):)?(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*)})`](https://regex101.com/r/fF5wQ3/2) works for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah for type validation.

Comment: Does my suggestion work for you? Do you have some more test cases?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm still working with it, I don't really get it to be honest, what does it do exactly?

Comment: Ignores consecutive `{...}` substrings and only handles another one that is not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That makes sense! Thank you, if it was an answer i'd accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118096/discussion-between-bas-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest matching 2 or more consecutive `{...}` blocks and ignore those matches, and only handle all other `{...}` (non-adjacent) blocks. Use the well-known PCRE [`(*SKIP)(*F)` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
(?:{(?:[a-zA-Z]:)?[a-zA-Z_]\w*}){2,}(*SKIP)(*F)|{(?:(?<type>[a-zA-Z]):)?(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fF5wQ3/3)

**Explanation**:

- `(?:{(?:[a-zA-Z]:)?[a-zA-Z_]\w*}){2,}(*SKIP)(*F)` - The first alternative branch (of the 2) in the regex that matches the pattern explained below (just without capture groups) that appear in succession, see `{2,}` that means *match 2 or more occurrences* at a stretch. The `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs make the regex engine omit this match and proceed.
- `|` - or match what we need:
- `{` - an open `{`
- `(?:(?<type>[a-zA-Z]):)?` - an optional group matching an ASCII letter (captured into Group "type") and a `:`
- `(?<name>[a-zA-Z_]\w*)` - Group "name" capturing an ASCII letter or `_` (see `[a-zA-Z_]` followed with 0+ word chars (from the `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` range)
- `}` - closing `}`

Comment: This just got alot more complicated, thanks for the explaination.

Comment: Once you understand what the pattern is matching, it won't be hard.

Comment: At first, there was `(?<!})` and `(?!{)`, where are they now? Is the thing you wrote at the beginning of the full regex the same?

Comment: Read my explanation in the answer. We match consecutive `{}` blocks, then discard them. Only matched blocks are standalone ones. If we use the lookbehind `(?<!})` with the lookahead `(?!{)` we will also exclude cases where the `{}` block is just preceded with `}` **OR** followed with `{`. And there is no guarentee there is a whole block there. We can check for a block *after* a block, but we cannot check for a block *before* a block. Certainly, you can use the lookaround approach *if*  you are sure there will only be `{}` around *blocks*.